# Color glitches in Chrome on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: google-chrome, vmware, 22.04, colors

I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 using VMware Workstation 16. Then I installed Google Chrome and noticed color glitches: a random blob of color appears and blocks me from viewing the webpage. Here is an image of it happening:

[image: screenshot showing the issue]

I tried forcing color profile in `chrome://flags` but to no avail. I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling Chrome multiple times.

Any ideas of how this would happen and how I could fix this?

Comment: Same problem here, also using VMWare, Google Chrome and Ubuntu 22.04. Therefore, it doesn't seem to be a local problem.

Comment: Installing via https://flatpak.org/ also works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enabling *Vulkan* graphics backend solved the problem for me:

1. Open a new tab in Chrome
2. Go to `chrome://flags`
3. Search for `Vulkan` and set it to `Enabled`
4. Click on the `Relaunch` button to restart Chrome

Comment: This works great for us so far. Much better than disabling GPU.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling graphics acceleration in Chrome solved the problem for me.

You can do that by clicking <kbd>⋮</kbd> in the top right of Chrome and then going to *Settings* → *Advanced* → *System* and toggling *Use hardware acceleration when available* off. After that relaunch Chrome for the changes to take effect.